# Getting range of max product subarray using Kadanes algorithm

Tags: algorithm, kadanes-algorithm

Applying Kadane algorithm to get max product subarray seems tricky. While I am able to get the max product, I am not really getting the correct range of the max product subarray.

http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/maximum-product-subarray/   explains the way to get the max product but I dont get how we can get the range of the subarray.

Can someone help me understand the range issue? This is a standard interview question and I want to make sure I understand the logic for the product case instead of just saying that the max sum subarray can be modified to answer max product subarray case.

thanks!!

Comment: it is not kadane's algorithm rather is similar to that.

Answer (score 1):

The link you have provided seems to assume that all the elements are positive. However in my opinion this is not a safe assumption. I have return code to get sub array for maximum product. I have used the same logic used in [Kadane's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem) algorithm. Code seems to work for me for all kinds of input. Please let me know if there are issues.

```
public static int[] getMaxSubArray(int []arr){

    int maxEndingHere = arr[0], maxSoFar = arr[0], startIndex =0, start =0,end=0;

    for(int i=1;i<arr.length;i++){

        if(maxEndingHere<0){
            maxEndingHere = arr[i];
            startIndex = i;         
        }else{          
            maxEndingHere *= arr[i];
        }           
        if(maxEndingHere>=maxSoFar){
            maxSoFar = maxEndingHere;
            start = startIndex;
            end = i;
        }   
    }       
    if(start<=end)
        return Arrays.copyOfRange(arr, start, end+1);

    return null;
}
```

1. Sample input = `{6, 3, -10, 0, 2}`
          *Output       = `{6,3}`*
2. Sample input = `{-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4}`
          *Output       = `{4}`*
3. Sample input = `{-1,-2,-9,-6}`
          *Output       = `{-1}`*

Comment: Sample input = {-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4} Output = {-2,1,-3,4,-1,2,1,-5,4}

Answer (score 1):

```
def max_subarray(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = 0
    max_start = start = 0
    max_end = end = 0

    # the range is [max_start, max_end)

    for i, x in enumerate(A):
        if max_ending_here + x > 0:
            max_ending_here = max_ending_here + x
            end = i+1
        else:
            max_ending_here = 0
            start = end = i

        if max_ending_here > max_so_far:
            max_so_far = max_ending_here
            max_start = start
            max_end = end

    return (max_start, max_end)
```

Answer (score 1):

It has basically three cases:

1. current number is +ve
2. current number is -ve
3. current number is 0

You need to have two variable:

- `min` which hold minimum value till now
- `max` which holds the maximum value till now.

Now for `case 3` `min` and `max` will be reset to 1.

For `case 1`: `max` will be `max * a[i]` and `min` will be minimum of `min*a[i]` and `1.`

For `case 2`: `max` will be maximum of `a[i] * min` and `1`, but the `min` value will be `max * a[i].`

Below is the code:

```
private static int getMaxProduct(int[] a){
    int minCurrent = 1, maxCurrent = 1, max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    for (int current : a) {
        if (current > 0) {
            maxCurrent = maxCurrent * current;
            minCurrent = Math.min(minCurrent * current, 1);
        } else if (current == 0) {
            maxCurrent = 1;
            minCurrent = 1;
        } else {
            int x = maxCurrent;
            maxCurrent = Math.max(minCurrent * current, 1);
            minCurrent = x * current;
        }
        if (max < maxCurrent) {
            max = maxCurrent;
        }
    }
    //System.out.println(minCurrent);
    return max;
}
```